# Memory metrics from client side in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, caching, server, ignite

> i need to print memory metrics in client side, 
>   using this following code is it possible?

```
java.util.Collection<DataRegionMetrics> regionsMetrics = ignite.dataRegionMetrics();
    for (DataRegionMetrics metrics : regionsMetrics) {
        System.out.println(">>> Memory Region Name: " + metrics.getName());
        System.out.println(">>> Allocation Rate: " + metrics.getAllocationRate());
        System.out.println(">>> Fill Factor: " + metrics.getPagesFillFactor());
        System.out.println(">>> Allocated Size: " + metrics.getTotalAllocatedSize());
        System.out.println(">>> Physical Memory Size: " + metrics.getPhysicalMemorySize());
    }
```

> this code successfully printed all the values, when i added to server code. but i need print all the values from client side.
>   i think ignite.dataRegionMetrics() this ignite is refer to server, How i get the server ( here is ignite) from client? is there any way for this like SERVER.get()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a compute task to server node perhaps?

One which will run this code but printing in to a StringBuilder, then returning it to client?

Comment: No, actually my aim is starting the server node by using cmd prompt, and client by Java code. from that client java code i need to print memory metrics.

Comment: From the client you can send compute tasks to server node.